# How to enable enable Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, vt-x

My laptop running Windows 10 Home edition. Its processor is an `AMD A6-4400M APU with Radeon HD Graphics`, DirectX version 11.2. In BIOS `CPU VT(VT-x)` is **supported** and `NX bit` enabled. But I couldn't see the Hyper-V option in `Turn Windows features on or off` section.

What is going wrong?

Comment: You cannot enable Hyper-V if you are using `Windows 10 Home`.  You should use either `Oracle VirtualBox` or `VMWare Workstation`.  If you really want to use Hyper-V upgrade to `Windows 10 Professional`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Hyper-V you have to upgarde to at least Windows 10 Pro. The Home Edition doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is only supported on the Pro and Enterprise editions.

> The following prerequisites are required to successfully run Client
>   Hyper-V on Windows 10:
>
> - Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise 64 bit Operating System
> - 64 bit processor with Second Level Address Translation (SLAT)
> - 4GB system RAM at minimum
> - BIOS-level Hardware Virtualization support

[Enabling Hyper-V for use on Windows 10](http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2015/09/09/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10.aspx)